# OpenCV2 / Python - How to ignore brightness with image matching function

Tags: python, opencv, detection, brightness

My goal is to detect a movement on the camera.

The code below works, but sometimes **when the brightness changes, It enables the capture as If a movement was detected**.

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2
import time
import numpy
from os.path import expanduser
try:
   import cPickle as pickle
except:
   import pickle


def matchFrame(image1,image2):
    origin = image1
    origin=cv2.cvtColor(origin, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    image = image2
    result = cv2.matchTemplate(origin, image, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    minVal,maxVal,minLoc,maxLoc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
    threshold = 0.90
    loc = numpy.where( result >= threshold)
    if loc[0].size==0 and loc[1].size==0:
        return False
    else:
        return True


def run():


    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    ret, firstframe = cap.read()
    inc=0
    while True:
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            if matchFrame(firstframe,gray):
                pass
            else:
                cv2.imwrite("path%s"%inc);
                inc=inc+1

            cv2.waitKey(1)
if __name__ == "\__main\__"
    run()
```

The method "**matchFrame**" use `cv2.matchTemplate(origin, image, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)` to compare image. If they are similar, It returns **False** I already tried to change the threshold but It does not work.

The method "**run**" is for the video capture and call the method above to compare the first frame with the current frame.

I personnaly think that It's all about **cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED**...

Do you have any suggestions?